# Clicking a button with VBA is not redirecting to a new page but redirecting when clicked manually

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am working with VBA to automate routines for repetetive tasks. My application has a page with lot of data(this page has atleast 1000 records) and few buttons.
One of the button clicks should redirect to a new page. My script waits until the page with the records load completely to click the button and when the button is clicked it should load new page but it just loads the same page instead of redirecting to a new page. But when the button when clicked manually, new page is loaded.

Button html:

```
<input type="image" name="btnadduser" id="btnAddUserid" src="../images/buttons/btn_add.gif" alt="Add New User" style="border-width:0px;" border="0">
```

To click this button from VBA:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend    
IE.document.getElementById("btnAddUserid").Click //this is the button which is not redirecting.
```

I don't have access to the actual functions of the code. So I don't know what is going on in the background. But the other buttons except this one work fine. How should I handle this issue?

Comment: If you can click the button manually, then you can click it via the code. Given the information you are providing, the code you posted looks correct. The only way you have to get more help here is to share the URL of your website and the full code you're using.

Comment: @Matteo NNZ Thanks for the reply. My script is clicking the button but its not redirecting to the page it is supposed to redirect, it is loading the same page after that click.

Comment: If you don't share the link of the webpage, we can't do much, sorry.

Comment: An image-type input acting as a submit button also sends the x and y coordinates of the click  - don't think that happens if you click the button via code, and it's possible the server may be checking for the x/y parameters.

Comment: @TimWilliams I will try to request access to the actual Javascript code for this button and figure out if coordinates are the issue or some timeout issue. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

1) Adding a click event and firing that

2) Using javascript to simulate clicking

3) Using FireEvent "onclick"

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub PerformClick()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "url"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        '#1
        Dim event_onClick As Object
        Set event_onClick = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        event_onClick.initEvent "click", True, False

        With .document.querySelector("#btnAddUserid")
             '#3
            .FireEvent "onclick"
             '#1
            .dispatchEvent event_onClick
        End With

        'Or #2
        ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('#btnAddUserid').click();"
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr I tried running your script and I am getting error on Set event_onClick = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"). VBA is not recognizing the function.

Comment: Try the other lines first then and comment out the those for #1 for now

Comment: Is there any reference to add in the library or something else before execution of the querySelector method. I tried running the #2 option too but no luck.

Comment: No. What error message did you get with #2?  Have you already got Microsoft Internet Control and Microsoft HTML Object library added? (Don't think you should need the second). And I guess there is always number 3.

Comment: I am getting this error "Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101". Looks like this is some time out error. Do you have any idea what this error says?

Comment: Try ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "document.getElementById('btnAddUserid').click();"

Comment: And what number where you trying when you got that message?

Comment: So this line didn't give me any error and clicked the button but did not redirect to a new page just loaded the same page. I was trying #2 and I already have the references added.

Comment: I’m not sure what to suggest. I would try to get the adding events version to work. Also, verify that this is the correct element to select for the fire off the new page.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. Will update you once I get around this.

Comment: If possible for you than I suggest you to share the link of that page may help us to test the code with it to check for the result and the cause for the issue. it can help to narrow down the issue. Thanks for your understanding.